# Java comparing two text files and writing diffs

Tags: java

Im really new to java and i need to make something that shows the differences between two txt files and writes diffs to another file. Im working on it for 4 days but i really cant get nothing other than this code. Can someone review it and help me with that?

```
public class TxtCompare
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("x"));
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("x"));
         
        String line1 = reader1.readLine();
        String line2 = reader2.readLine();
         
        boolean areEqual = true;
        int lineNum = 1;
         
        while (line1 != null || line2 != null)
        {
            if(line1 == null || line2 == null)
            {
                areEqual = false;
                break;
            }
            else if(! line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2))
            {
                areEqual = false;
                break;
            }
            line1 = reader1.readLine();
            line2 = reader2.readLine();
            lineNum++;
        }
         
        if(areEqual)
        {
            System.out.println("Two files have same content.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Two files have different content. They differ at line "+lineNum);
             
            System.out.println("File1 has "+line1+" and File2 has "+line2+" at line "+lineNum);
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? One thing you shouldn't do is compare 2 lines and then overwrite them by reading another line from the files. First read the lines and then compare them. You might want to do a do-while loop here with the condition you already have.

Comment: Btw, you might want to read [ask] in order to improve your question.

Comment: The code seems working fine to me, what exactly do you expect?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. This code only finds a single difference and i dont know how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to track differences depends on the requirements, e.g. whether inserted or deleted files should be detected as well. Since you are a beginner the requirements probably are quite simple, i.e. if we have files like `ABC` and `ACD` (each character representing a line) the differences probably should be `line 2: B<>C` and `line 3: C<>D`.

To gather those differences you could do the following (I'll omit some stuff to keep code simple, e.g. proper getters and setters):

Create a class to hold the differences:

```
class Difference {
  private int lineNumber;
  private String file1Line;        
  private String file2Line;

  //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Then keep a `List<Difference>` and fill it like this:

```
String line1;
String line2; 
int lineNumber = 0;

List<Difference> differences = new LinkedList<>();

do {
  line1 = reader1.readLine();
  line2 = reader2.readLine();
  lineNumber++; //first line will have number 1

  //we've hit the end of file1
  if( line1 == null ) {
    //if we've not hit the end of file2 yet, we have a difference
    if( line2 != null ) {
      differences.add(new Difference(lineNumber, line1, line2));
    }
  } 
  //if we didn't hit the end of file1 yet we just compare, this will return false if:
  // - file2 contains a different line
  // - we've hit the end of file2 in which case line2 is null
  else if(!line1.equals(line2)  {
    differences.add(new Difference(lineNumber, line1, line2));
  }

  //once we've hit the end of either file we'll stop this loop
} while( line1 != null && line2 != null );

//read the remaining lines of both files
//since we hit the end of at least one line in the previous loop, only one of the following loops should, if at all
//if we already hit the end of file1 in the first loop, line1 should be null at this point and we won't enter this loop
while( line1 != null ) {
  line1 = reader1.readLine();
  lineNumber++;
  differences.add(new Difference(lineNumber, line1, null));
}

//if we already hit the end of file2 in the first loop, line2 should be null at this point and we won't enter this loop    
while( line2 != null ) {
  line2 = reader2.readLine();
  lineNumber++;
  differences.add(new Difference(lineNumber, null, line2));
}
```

Now you should have a list of differences that you'd just need to write to a separate file. If that list is empty you didn't find any differences which means the files are equal (at least the lines are, the files might still have different line separators etc. but I guess that's no concern for you atm).

Note that you'd have to handle exceptions, closing the files and readers (see Matt's answer) etc. as well.

Please also note that you could do everything with less code (e.g. only one loop) but since you're a beginner it's often best to write some more code to make the process easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as expected but can be simplified and improved.

The two if-statements in the loop have the same content and thus can be joined. This also removed one of the null-checks since it is already done in *equalsIgnoreCase*:

```java
if (line1 == null || !line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) {
    areEqual = false;
     break;
}
```

You can use try-with-resources for the two readers and remove the explicit calls to *close* as this done implicitly.

```java
try (BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
     BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"))) {
    // code here
}
```

---

As per your comment, you want to detect all differences between the two files. For this, you either need to store all occurrences in a data-structure and loop over this later (to print) when the files are not equal. A simpler possibility is to move the output into the loop like this:

```java
try (BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
     BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"))) {

    int lineNum = 1;
    boolean areEqual = true;
    while (true) {
        String line1 = reader1.readLine();
        String line2 = reader2.readLine();
        if (line1 == null && line2 == null) {
            break;
        } else if (line1 == null || !line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) {
            System.out.println("Two files have different content. They differ at line " + lineNum);
            System.out.println("File1 has " + line1 + " and File2 has " + line2 + " at line " + lineNum);
            areEqual = false;
        }
        lineNum++;
    }

    if (areEqual) {
        System.out.println("Two files have same content.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem i have is it only finds one difference and i have no idea how to fix that. Output is [this](https://imgur.com/a/Z2fn4BA) . There's more than 30-40 lines of different things in txt files by the way.

Comment: @vintery See my updated answer with an example to output all differences.